# Getting ES6 class instances from a Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a base class, App (ES6 syntax); I want derived classes to be able to specify a several child components to be rendered -- depending on its state. E.g.,

```
class App {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>{ this.state.c1 }</div> 
      <div>{ this.state.c2 }</div> 
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends App {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      c1: <Foo/>,
      c2: <Bar/>
    }
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  getTitle() { return 'Foo'; }
}
```

I also need to have the base class App, call methods on the child components. E.g., `this.state.component.getTitle()`

However, `this.state.c1` is not the ES6 class (i.e., not an instance of Foo).

I can't use refs, since the base class doesn't create the `<Foo/>` component.

I can't use composition, since App requires multiple child components.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figure the most appropriate approach is to invert the dependency.

I.e., "inject" a Model class into each component as a property. Then access the property from the base class.